# Using end of word mark with unicode in regular expressions in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode, right-to-left

The following matches in Idle, but does not match when run in a method in a module file:

```
import re
re.search('\\bשלום\\b','שלום עולם',re.UNICODE)
```

while the following matches in both cases:

```
import re
re.search('שלום','שלום עולם',re.UNICODE)
```

(Notice that stackoverflow erroneously switches the first and second items in the line above as this is a right to left language)

How can I make the first code match inside a py file?

Update: What I should have written for the first segment is that it matches in Idle, but does not match when run in eclipse console with PyDev.

Comment: The first re.search() doesn't work for me in IDLE or a module.

Comment: Did you try `re.LOCALE` instead of UNICODE? I'd install locale-he but am kind of afraid I'd never get it switched back. Off-topic: some say google translate goes too far `apt-get install user-he; hebrew-settings` becomes `apt-get install user-en; english-settings` which is impressive, but wrong ;)

Comment: @Lee, nor does the first for me, although the second does. I mention this as we are probably both in a non-he locale and soooo many things depend upon it. Oddly, it got the paste order correct.

Comment: Thanks for checking guys. I don't think I have anything set specifically to Hebrew, just to unicode. Idle\Options\Configure IDLE\General\Default Source Encoding is set to UTF-8   and in C:\Python26\Lib\site.py I have encoding = "utf-8" instead of encoding = "ascii". Also make sure you're usign a unicode supporting font such as Courier or Courier New

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work for me when I'm using unicode strings:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
match = re.search(u'\\bשלום\\b', u'שלום עולם', re.U)
```

See it in action: http://codepad.org/xWz5cZj5

Comment: Is the `# coding=utf-8` notation the same as `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`? I'm asking because it's the first time I see it like this. If not, please correct it.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ - sorry to disappoint you, but I don't know. `:|` I don't know any Python, in fact, and learned every bit from Google and the documentations. I did that odd thing because I want to learn Python (one day), and I know Hebrew.

Comment: No disappointment here, don't worry; you did fine for someone not knowing Python :) It was possible that there was an alternative notation that I didn't know. I corrected it for you.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ - No problem. The code I posted doesn't work without it, but I guess codepad.org isn't an accurate representation. Thanks!

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ: See http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#encoding-declarations